# How to select or delete node xml by using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

How to select or delete node xml by using XSLT? I want to select `category` Node by comparing startDate and enddate

This is my xml

```
<Book>
    <Book>
        <startDate>2005-02-14T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        <endDate>2015-01-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        <record>
            <location>XXX</location>
            <telephone>0891234</telephone>
            <category>
                <name>ABC</name>
                <startdate>2005-02-14</startdate>
                <endDate>2015-01-31</endDate>
            </category>
            <category>
                <name>XYZ</name>
                <startdate>2015-02-01</startdate>
                <endDate>9999-12-31</endDate>
            </category>
        </record>
        <Author>Manu</Author>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <startDate>2005-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        <endDate>9999-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        <record>
            <location>XXX</location>
            <telephone>0891234</telephone>
            <category>
                <name>ABC</name>
                <startdate>2005-02-14</startdate>
                <endDate>2015-01-31</endDate>
            </category>
            <category>
                <name>XYZ</name>
                <startdate>2005-02-01</startdate>
                <endDate>9999-12-31</endDate>
            </category>
        </record>
        <Author>Liverpool</Author>
    </Book>
</Book>
```

I want to select `category` Node that there are `\\category\startDate` equal to `\\book\startDate`  and `\\category\endDate` equal to `\\book\endDate` (ignore Timestamp at `\\book\startDate` and  `\\book\endDate` just only company year, month and day)

This is expected result

```
<Book>
    <Book>
        <startDate>2005-02-14T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        <endDate>2015-01-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        <record>
            <location>XXX</location>
            <telephone>0891234</telephone>
            <category>
                <name>ABC</name>
                <startDate>2005-02-14</startDate>
                <endDate>2015-01-31</endDate>
            </category>
        </record>
        <Author>Manu</Author>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <startDate>2005-02-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        <endDate>9999-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
        <record>
            <location>XXX</location>
            <telephone>0891234</telephone>
            <category>
                <name>XYZ</name>
                <startDate>2005-02-01</startDate>
                <endDate>9999-12-31</endDate>
            </category>
        </record>
        <Author>Liverpool</Author>
    </Book>
</Book>
```

How should I do?  This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="category">
    <xsl:if test="//category/startDate = //Book/startDate and //category/endDate = //Book/endDate">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity template (the first template in your code) plus an empty template

```
<xsl:template match="category[not(startdate = substring(ancestor::Book/startDate, 1, 10) and endDate = substring(ancestor::Book/endDate, 1, 10))]"/>
```

to not copy the `category` elements you want to delete might help.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEJ

Comment: Sorry I adjusted category-start_date in  second Book  to be '2005-02-01'

Comment: @BellAimsaard, see the edit, my suggestion is just one example on how to approach that if you start with the identity transformation and put the condition of the elements you want to remove in the match pattern of an empty template.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion